# How many records are reasonable to manage on one Custom Meta data?

Tags: custom-metadata

I want to know that how many records are reasonable to manage on one Custom MetaData?
We have a plan to manage near 30000 records on one Custom Metadata. Each record is not large, but I believe it's too much to handle one Custom MetaData.
If you have the experience to manage a huge number of records in one Custom Meta Data, please give me your advice.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe that you have x/y problem here. Answer for your question is: having 30k custom metadata objects is not a big problem in terms of an amount of it from Salesforce perspective. But there can be other problems like storing them in VCS, deployment times, processing times/hitting governor limits for complicated computations  when using all 30k records at once etc
I think that source of the issues is idea of creating 30k record of custom metdata itself. Why? Custom metadata is usually created as something to store settings for organization. 30k settings would indicate that org is MASSIVE

Comment: Agreed about this being an X/Y problem. Looking at [limitations for custom metadata](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_limits.htm&type=5) it sounds like you could conceivably fit this into the limits but you'll likely encounter new logistical problems. Can you update your question to include _why_ you want to use 30,000 custom metadata records?

Comment: This might not be possible. You're limited to 10,000,000 characters of data *per org* (not just per Custom Metadata Type); that's only 333 characters per record, and character counts are based on record size times maximum field sizes, so you'll have to carefully trim your field sizes to maximize real estate. In addition, the CMT importer only supports 200 records at a time, so that's 150 imports, or you'll have to write your own custom CMT loader. It'll also be unwieldy to use in a git repository, because you'll also have 30,000 files in a single folder.

Comment: This would also result in you encountering, should you attempt to deploy this whole set at once, otherwise-uncommon Metadata API limits, like maximum files deployed and possibly even deployment size.